Decomposition Redox Rxn Vs. Intramolecular Redox Rxn
I'm trying to understand what is the difference between decomposition redox reaction and intramolecular redox reaction? Are they synonymous? Is there a reaction which belongs to one but not the other category.

I see the following similarities -

Both the reactions start with a reactant producing more than 1 products.
Both require different element atoms within the same molecule of reactant to undergo change in oxidation number thus getting oxidised or reduced.


Please point out what distinguishes them from each other. Thank you.
Edit - I've edited my question, so kindly re-address it.

What is the source for that blockquote?

I was taught that in class, so can't cite any source.

Don't put your own idea as if it was a citation. Also you are practically making stuff up. Nobody calls "intramolecular redox reactions" like that, it's for ex. rearrangements, etc. Organic chemistry downplays redox aspects.

Many decomposition redox reactions are not intramolecular redox reactions.
Typical cases are radical chain reactions with catalytic effect of other minor compounds. Like the ozone decomposition, occuring in stratosphere, involving nitrogen oxides from airliner engines,
$$\ce{O3 + NO -> O2 + NO2}$$
$$\ce{NO2 + O -> NO + O2}$$
or chlorine atoms released from freons by photolysis.
$$\ce{Cl + O3 -> ClO + O2}$$
$$\ce{ClO + O -> Cl + O2}$$
Another case is
$$\ce{3 ClO- -> 2 Cl- + ClO3-}$$

The opposite, if every intramolecular redox reaction is a decomposition redox reaction is quite tricky, depending on what we consider generally as decomposition (redox or not), regarding elimination of a second product.
But there are some even without a second product elimination that in addition cannot be considered as decomposition.
Like the keto-enol tautomerism,
$$\ce{R-CO-CH2-R <-> R-C(OH)=CH-R}$$
or nitroso-oxime tautomerism,
$$\ce{R2CH-NO <-> R2C=N-OH}$$
or isomerization reactions like
$$\ce{CH3-CH2-CH=CH2 -> CH3-CH=CH-CH3}$$
While these reactions are formally redox reactions, there are rarely called like that in organic chemistry.

Sorry but I had mentioned intramolecular not intermolecular. Could you please add that piece of information

Ah, I am sorry, it had to be an oversight on my side. I will think about it.
